# What is the impact of an object allocation on the binary size?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

### Background

I have a `VS2013` solution containing  many projects an numerous sources.
In my sources, I use the same macro thousands of times in different locations in the sources.

Something like:

```
#define MyMacro(X) X
```

where `X` is `const char*`

I have a DLL project, that with the above macro definition result in a 800KB output dll size.

### Problem

In some scenarios or modes, I wish to change my macro definition to the following:

```
#define MyMacro(X) Utils::MyFunc(X)
```

This change had a very unpleasant side effect which result in the DLL output file size **increasing by 100KB**.

### Notes

1. `Utils::MyFunc()` is used for the first time. So, naturally, I except the binary to increase (a little) since a new code is introduces
2. `Utils::MyFunc()` does not include large header or libs.
3. `Utils::MyFunc()` does allocate `string` object.
4. All projects are compiled using definitions to favor small code.

### Artificial example

```
#define M1(X) X
#define M2(X) ReturnString1(X)
#define M3(X) ReturnString2(X)

string ReturnString1(const char* c)
{
    return string(c);
}

string ReturnString2(const string& s)
{
    return string(s);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    M3("TEST");
    M3("TEST");

    .
    . // 5000 times
    .
    
    M3("TEST");
    return 1;
}
```

In the above example, I've generate a small EXE project to try and mimic the problem I'm facing.

Using `M1` exclusively in `_tmain` - compilation was instantaneous and output file was 88KB EXE.
Using `M2` exclusively in `_tmain` - compilation took minutes and output file was 239KB EXE.
Using `M3` exclusively in `_tmain` - compilation took a lot longer and output file was 587KB EXE.

I used [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) to compare between the binaries and extracted the function names from the binaries.
In `M2` & `M3`, I see a lot more of the following functions than I see in `M1`:

```
... $basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@...
```

I'm not too surprised about it since in `M2` & `M3` I'm allocating a `string` object.
But is it enough to justify a 151KB & 499KB increase?

### Question

Is it expected from string allocation to have such a substantial impact on the output file size?

Comment: What happens if you put `__declspec(noinline)` before `string ReturnString1` and `...2`?

Comment: Define "DLL output file size increasing by 100KB". Just because the file is bigger doesn't mean that the code is bigger. Unless you're stripping debug data when building the output object file, this kind of a change can certainly add additional debug data to the output object file.

Comment: Have you looked at a disassembly?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If I may, let's look at the `artificial example` I've played with. It was all build with the same configuration. Even though I'm generating PDB file, It shouldn't effect the DLL size (to my knowledge)

Comment: @JohnZwinck seems to remain the same size. Just verified `M2` use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another "artificial" example:

```
int main()
{
    const char* p = M1("TEST");
    std::cout << p;

    string s = M3("TEST");
    std::cout << s;
    return 1;
}
```

I have commented one section at a time and looked at the generated ASM. For the `M1` macro, I got:

```
012B1000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [_imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A (012B204Ch)]  
012B1006  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (012B1020h)  
012B100B  mov         eax,1
```

While for `M3`:

```
00DC1068  push        4  
00DC106A  push        ecx  
00DC106B  lea         ecx,[ebp-40h]  
00DC106E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],0Fh  
00DC1075  mov         dword ptr [ebp-30h],0  
00DC107C  mov         byte ptr [ebp-40h],0  
00DC1080  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign (0DC1820h)  
00DC1085  lea         edx,[ebp-40h]  
00DC1088  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
00DC108F  lea         ecx,[s]  
00DC1092  call        ReturnString2 (0DC1000h)  
00DC1097  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],2  
00DC109B  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
00DC109E  cmp         eax,10h  
00DC10A1  jb          main+6Dh (0DC10ADh)  
00DC10A3  inc         eax  
00DC10A4  push        eax  
00DC10A5  push        dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
00DC10A8  call        std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate (0DC17C0h)  
00DC10AD  mov         ecx,dword ptr [_imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A (0DC3050h)]  
00DC10B3  lea         edx,[s]  
00DC10B6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],0Fh  
00DC10BD  mov         dword ptr [ebp-30h],0  
00DC10C4  mov         byte ptr [ebp-40h],0  
00DC10C8  call        std::operator<<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (0DC1100h)  
00DC10CD  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
00DC10D0  cmp         eax,10h  
00DC10D3  jb          main+9Fh (0DC10DFh)  
00DC10D5  inc         eax  
00DC10D6  push        eax  
00DC10D7  push        dword ptr [s]  
00DC10DA  call        std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate (0DC17C0h)  
00DC10DF  mov         eax,1
```

Looking at the first column (addresses), the `M1` code size is 12, while `M3` - 119.

I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out the difference between `5,000 * 12` and `5,000 * 119` :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take two cases in a simple example:

```
int _tmain()
{
    "TEST";
    std::string("TEST");
}
```

The first statement has no effect and is trivially optimized away.

The second statement constructs a string, which requires a function call.  But what function is called?  Maybe it's the string constructor, but if that's inlined, it might actually be that `malloc()`, `strlen()`, and `memcpy()` are called directly from main (not explicitly, but those three functions might plausibly be used by a string constructor which could be inline).

Now if you have this:

```
    std::string("TEST");
    std::string("TEST");
    std::string("TEST");
```

You can see it's not 3 function calls, but 9 (in our hypothetical).  You could get it back to 3 if you make sure the function you're calling is **not** inline (either using `__declspec(noinline)` or by defining it in a separate translation unit, aka .cpp file).

You may find that enabling full optimizations (Release build) lets the compiler figure out that these strings are never used, and get rid of them.  Maybe.

Comment: Isn't all of this a non op since they are unused temporaries?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know that you can make that assumption; the constructor could have side effects.

Comment: In the real case (not the artificial one), all the strings are different and used.